# I need help understanding the quotient of an equivalence relation

Tags: advice

I understand it in theory,but not in practice
So here is the exampl

1. LetA={a,b,c,d,e,f}
2. G,H be equivalence relation in A

3.G=$1_a$ $\cup$ {(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(a,c),  (c,a),(d,e),(e,d)}

H=$1_a$ $\cup$ {(b,c),(c,b)}

Find A/G

Here is my guess

A/G=G

Any help would be mighty appreciated to figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is related to $b$ under the equivalence relation given by $G$, $b$ is related to $c$, so $a$ is related to $b$ and by transitivity to $c$, hence the equivalence class of $a$ is the subset $\{a,b,c\}$ of $A$. Then $d$ is related to $e$ and $f$ is related to $f$ itself. Hence the set of distinct equivalence classes of $A$ modulo $G$ is given by $\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}$, and $\{f\}$.

Comment: Hence $A/G=\{\{a, b, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{f\} \}$

Comment: yes, I am editing, thanks

Comment: So in A/G you are checking transitivity in G?
So for

Comment: You don't need to check transitivity, by assumption you have that $G$ is an equivalence relation, that is, reflexive, symmetric and transitive. I am using transitivity to put elements of $A$ into classes of $A/G$.

Comment: Ok
So what do I have to do in general? Use any of the given properties.
So A/H={b,c} ? b is related to c under the equiv. relation of under H and c to b.

Comment: $G/H=\{ \{a\}, \{b,c\}, \{d\}, \{e\}, \{f\}\}$

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain how you got it ? Looking at H, by assumption bHc-> cHb and all the other are singletons . Thus you get your set?

Comment: Don't forget reflexivity: for each $a\in A$, $a$ is in the class $[a]$ represented by $a$, both with respect to $H$ and to $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the help